# How to stop browser from showing php warnings

Tags: php, nginx, redis, php-8

I upgraded my server to CentOS Stream and PHP to PHP 8.2.0RC4 (cli)

I have set all combinations of display_startup_errors and display_errors in php ini to off as well as in php-fpm

In php-fpm I added:

```
php_admin_value[display_errors] = Off
php_flag[display_errors] = Off
php_value[display_errors] = Off

php_admin_value[display_startup_errors] = Off
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = Off
php_value[display_startup_errors] = Off


php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ERROR
php_flag[error_reporting] = E_ERROR
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ERROR
```

I have restarted nginx and php-fpm after each change and cleared the redis cache.

The site still shows a bunch of these:

Unknown: Creation of dynamic property Request::$request is deprecated in

Where else can I look to get rid of these?  I vaguely remember a long time ago that something else had to be done to suppress exceptions, but am lost.

This did not happen under the PHP 7.4 I was running.  How do I stop these from showing?

Answer (score 0):

This is on OpenCart.  The error is actually being generated by the OpenCart error handler.  The setting for error_display is not exposed in the UI, only for config_error_display.    error_display is set in system/config/default.php which is odd because as everyone knows, you do not edit core framework files.

Anyway, I ruled out the issue being in the nginx stack because of the **error** surrounding each error.

Hope this helps someone someday.